# How to parse XML to CSV where data is in attributes only

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, text-files

The XML file I am trying to parse has all the data contained in attributes. I found how to build the string to insert into the text file.

I have this XML file:

```
<ig:prescribed_item class_ref="0161-1#01-765557#1">
  <ig:prescribed_property property_ref="0161-1#02-016058#1" is_required="false" combination_allowed="false" one_of_allowed="false">
    <dt:measure_number_type representation_ref="0161-1#04-000005#1">
      <dt:real_type>
        <dt:real_format pattern="\d(1,)\.\d(1,)"/>
      </dt:real_type>
      <dt:prescribed_unit_of_measure UOM_ref="0161-1#05-003260#1"/>
    </dt:measure_number_type>
  </ig:prescribed_property>
  <ig:prescribed_property property_ref="0161-1#02-016059#1" is_required="false" combination_allowed="false" one_of_allowed="false">
    <dt:measure_number_type representation_ref="0161-1#04-000005#1">
      <dt:real_type>
        <dt:real_format pattern="\d(1,)\.\d(1,)"/>
      </dt:real_type>
      <dt:prescribed_unit_of_measure UOM_ref="0161-1#05-003260#1"/>
    </dt:measure_number_type>
  </ig:prescribed_property>
</ig:prescribed_item>
  </ig:identification_guide>
```

And I want to parse it into a text file like this with the class ref duplicated for each property:

```
class_ref|property_ref|is_required|UOM_ref
0161-1#01-765557#1|0161-1#02-016058#1|false|0161-1#05-003260#1
0161-1#01-765557#1|0161-1#02-016059#1|false|0161-1#05-003260#1
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("file.xml"), 'UTF-8') do |config|
  config.strict
end

content = doc.xpath("//ig:prescribed_item/@class_ref").map {|i|
  i.search("//ig:prescribed_item/ig:prescribed_property/@property_ref").map { |d| d.text }
}

puts content.inspect

content.each do |c|
  puts c.join('|')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simplify it a bit using CSS accessors:

```
xml = <<EOT
<ig:prescribed_item class_ref="0161-1#01-765557#1">
    <ig:prescribed_property property_ref="0161-1#02-016058#1" is_required="false" combination_allowed="false" one_of_allowed="false">
        <dt:measure_number_type representation_ref="0161-1#04-000005#1">
            <dt:real_type>
                <dt:real_format pattern="\d(1,)\.\d(1,)"/>
            </dt:real_type>
            <dt:prescribed_unit_of_measure UOM_ref="0161-1#05-003260#1"/>
        </dt:measure_number_type>
    </ig:prescribed_property>
    <ig:prescribed_property property_ref="0161-1#02-016059#1" is_required="false" combination_allowed="false" one_of_allowed="false">
        <dt:measure_number_type representation_ref="0161-1#04-000005#1">
            <dt:real_type>
                <dt:real_format pattern="\d(1,)\.\d(1,)"/>
            </dt:real_type>
            <dt:prescribed_unit_of_measure UOM_ref="0161-1#05-003260#1"/>
        </dt:measure_number_type>
    </ig:prescribed_property>
</ig:prescribed_item>
</ig:identification_guide>
EOT

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

data = [ %w[ class_ref property_ref is_required UOM_ref] ]

doc.css('|prescribed_item').each do |pi|
  pi.css('|prescribed_property').each do |pp|
    data << [
      pi['class_ref'],
      pp['property_ref'],
      pp['is_required'],
      pp.at_css('|prescribed_unit_of_measure')['UOM_ref']
    ]
  end
end

puts data.map{ |row| row.join('|') }
```

Which outputs:

```
class_ref|property_ref|is_required|UOM_ref
0161-1#01-765557#1|0161-1#02-016058#1|false|0161-1#05-003260#1
0161-1#01-765557#1|0161-1#02-016059#1|false|0161-1#05-003260#1
```

---

> Could you explain this line in greater detail "`pp.at_css('|prescribed_unit_of_measure')['UOM_ref']`"

In Nokogiri, there are two types of "find a node" methods: The "search" methods return all nodes that match a particular accessor as a `NodeSet`, and the "at" methods return the first `Node` of the `NodeSet` which will be the first encountered Node that matched the accessor.

The "search" methods are things like `search`, `css`, `xpath` and `/`. The "at" methods are things like `at`, `at_css`, `at_xpath` and `%`. Both `search` and `at` accept either XPath or CSS accessors.

Back to `pp.at_css('|prescribed_unit_of_measure')['UOM_ref']`: At that point in the code `pp` is a local variable containing a "prescribed_property" Node. So, I'm telling the code to find the first node under `pp` that matches the CSS `|prescribed_unit_of_measure` accessor, in other words the first `<dt:prescribed_unit_of_measure>` tag contained by the `pp` node. When Nokogiri finds that node, it returns the value of the `UOM_ref` attribute of the node.

As a FYI, the `/` and `%` operators are aliased to `search` and `at` respectively in Nokogiri. They're part of its "Hpricot" compatability; We used to use them a lot when Hpricot was the XML/HTML parser of choice, but they're not idiomatic for most Nokogiri developers. I suspect it's to avoid confusion with the regular use of the operators, at least it is in my case.

Also, Nokogiri's CSS accessors have some extra-special juiciness; They support namespaces, like the XPath accessors do, only they use `|`. Nokogiri will let us ignore the namespaces, which is what I did. You'll want to nose around in the Nokogiri docs for CSS and namespaces for more information.

Comment: Tin, Thank you, I think this will work well. Thanks! If you would like I can send you some bitcoin.   My next step is to take the text generated format and build an xml file of the same schema.

Comment: Could you explain this line in greater detail "pp.at_css('|prescribed_unit_of_measure')['UOM_ref']"

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely ways of parsing based on attributes.

The Engine yard article "[Getting started with Nokogiri](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/)" has a full description.

But quickly, the examples they give are:

> To match “h3″ tags that have a class
>   attribute, we write:

```
h3[@class]
```

> To match “h3″ tags whose class
>   attribute is equal to the string “r”,
>   we write:

```
 h3[@class = "r"]
```

> Using the attribute matching
>   construct, we can modify our previous
>   query to:

```
 //h3[@class = "r"]/a[@class = "l"]
```

Comment: Taryn, Thank You. I will research the tutorial. However I think I have figured that part out, as you can see my code 'content = doc.xpath("//ig:prescribed_item/@class_ref").map {|i...' I understand how I can select based on attributes. I do not understand how to insert them into a text file so the format is as the example. Maybe you could take a look at my example above.

Comment: Ah ok - I misunderstood.

What do you get as output from the code you currently have?

Comment: '0161-1#02-016058#1|0161-1#02-016059#1' is the output i get now. Which lets me get the properties in a list, but i struggle to see how to get the desired out put from above, with column headers. And also, the xml could have any number of properties (/@property_ref) but will only have one class_ref.

Comment: Ok... at this point I think I've reached the limit of my knowledge ad I'm guessing. But surely there would be some kind of Nokogiri "attrs" method. You could call that on the nodes and store the data for each node in a Hash where the keys are the property-names and the values are the actual values. Then later you can get a list of all the keys - and that's the list of headings... the data is just the values (or nil if it doesn't have one for that heading).

Comment: If anyone has a more complete solution, that would help a lot!